# Multiplicity of the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ only has simple eigenvalues, are there properties concerning the multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ ?

This question is much narrower than the general Additive Eigenvalue Problem conjectured by Horn (1962) and demonstrated in 1999 by Knutson and Tao. We do not ask *what are the eigenvalues* of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$, but only *whether they are simple*.

Here is the statement:

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ be two symmetric matrices (i.e. in $\mathcal{S}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $). 
We suppose all eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ are simple (i.e. multiplicity 1) and $\boldsymbol{A}$ is invertible. 
There are no restrictions on the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{B}$, in particular it is likely that $0$ is an eigenvalue of high multiplicity. 
$\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ do not commute.

I conjecture that the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ are all simple (i.e. $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ has, as $\boldsymbol{A}$, only eigenvalues of multiplicity 1). However, a proof is still elusive. Can anyone help ?

Comment: This question ultimately was about the conditions for violation of the Wigner-von Neumann non-crossing rule, which was answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/q/261826

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is false. For example, take
$$
A = \left[\matrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 &0 & 0\\0 & 0 &3 & 0\\0 & 0& 0 & 4}\right].
$$
Then $A$ is symmetric, invertible, and has only simple eigenvalues, as requested.

Let
$$
B = \left[\matrix{ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -2 &0 & 0\\0 & 0 &0 & 1\\0 & 0& 1 & 0}\right].
$$
Then $B$ is symmetric, and $A$ and $B$ do not commute, as requested.

Now
$$ A + B = \left[\matrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\0 & 0 &3 & 1\\0 & 0& 1 & 4}\right].
$$
Clearly $A+B$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$, which shows that the conjecture is false.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to find a counterexample. Ultimately, I needed to further define the question, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This question ultimately was about the conditions for violation of the Wigner-von Neumann non-crossing rule, which was asked, and, answered here: [mathoverflow.net/q/261826](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261826)